# Redirect all except few IP address to 403.php page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am a novice, please help me, all i want is to redirect all other users to `403.php` page except for few specified IP address.

I am working on a wordpress site so `www.example.com/wp-admin` is the page (directory) which i want to redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this code in your htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$  # IP1 allowed
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$  # IP2 allowed
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$  # IP3 allowed
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(/.*)?$ /403.php [R,L]
```

Don't forget to replace `x` characters (you can add same line for each except IP you want).

Also, you want to redirect to `403.php` which means you want to forbid access (403).
You could use `F` flag (forbidden) instead

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^xx\.xxx\.xxx\.xx$
RewriteRule ^wp-admin(/.*)$ - [F]
```

Comment: thanx a lot for the help, but what i forgot to mention is redirection will only work if a perticular page is being access, in my case it is admin panel

Comment: What is **exactly** the entire URI path to your admin panel ? (What's the url to access it -you can replace your domain name by `domain.com` if you want-)

Comment: i am working on a wordpress site so www.example.com/wp-admin is the page which i want to redirect

Comment: I edited my answer. Don't forget to put this code **before** Wordpress' main rule